# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null in the template tag

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm getting a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null" error in my Vue/Laravel application. I get data from API. I can access data in the script tag for example in mounted method but in the template I can't access the data.

```
<template>

    <article class="hentry blog-post single-post single-post-v3">

        <router-link :to="'/kategori/'+post.category.slug" class="post-category bg-primary">{{post.category.title}}</router-link>

                        
        <h1 class="post-title">{{post.title}}</h1>
        
    ...

</template>

<script>
export default {
    components: {
        FeaturedPosts,
        Comments
    },
    async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {

        const returned = (await axios.get(route("api.post", to.params.slug))).data.response

        next(vm => {
            vm.post = returned.post;
            vm.comments = (returned.comments != undefined) ? returned.comments.data : null;
            vm.commentsPagination = (returned.comments != undefined) ? returned.comments : null;
        });

    },
    data() {
        return {

            post: null,
            comments: null,
            commentsPagination: null,

        };
    },
}
</script>
```

It gives "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'category')". I can access post.category in mounted() method but in the template I can't.

Answer (score 0):

`next(vm => ...)` callback is triggered after the instance is created, the state that is initialized there shouldn't be relied on because initial rendering occurs with uninitialized state.

It should be either:

```
return {
  post: [],
  ...
```

Or:

```
<article v-if="post" ...>
```